# ¿Cuál es la mejor traducción para "Goddamn"?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, vulgaridades

Ayer leía un cómic de Batman, escrito y dibujado por Snyder y Capullo y me encontré con que en una de las viñetas decía:

> "... It's the g-censored!-n Batman"

Con el "censored!" ya añadido por el editor. Me llamó la atención que ya saliese como "censurado". Ya hubo otras muchas historias que pusieron de moda el "goddamn Batman" o donde se hacía uso (no censurado) de la palabra.

[image: ASBAR goddamn Batman]

<sub>All Star Batman and Robin de Frank Miller</sub>

Entiendo que `goddamn` o `god damn` puede traducirse como `maldito` o `condenado`. Sin embargo, en otras traducciones de historias de Batman donde se usa *Goddamn* (por ejemplo en [Dark Knight Returns de Frank Miller](http://dkreturns.blogspot.com/2012/04/hiyo-god-damn-silver.html), donde se hace un uso casi exagerado de la *palabrita*) "goddamn" se traduce de maneras menos consistentes.

> God damn running dog... -> **Maldito** perro...
>
> OWW god damn it-- -> OWW **me cago en la leche**--
>
> Goddamn fascist son of bitches... -> **Me cago en** esos fascistas hijos de puta...
>
> Hiyo Goddamn silver  -> Hiyo el **jodido** Silver

Estas traducciones son de la versión *Absolute* de la novela gráfica de Planeta deAgostini (no especifica traductor), que creo que tampoco son consistentes con otras traducciones al español que he visto para la misma novela gráfica en otras versiones (formatos). De hecho esta version traduce "screw up" como "joderla" en vez de "fastidiarla" o "pifiarla", por lo que creo que el traductor de esta versión decidió darle un enfoque más adulto en la traducción. Aun así, `god damn` no se traduce de una manera consistente. Me sorprende no ver más "maldito" en lugar de "jodido" o "me cago en", pero tampoco tengo una medida para juzgar cómo de "fuerte" es "god damn" comparado con otros exabruptos (¿ligero, medio o fuerte?).

¿Cuál es la mejor traducción para `goddamn`?

Comment: +1 This question made me laugh- Remember that `me cago en la leche` is a VERY spanish(Spain) based expression. A good answer would take a globally recognized form.

Comment: GD es *muy* fuerte para la gente religiosa (conozco a gente que dirán palabrotas cada dos por tres, pero rechazan decir GD), pero diría que para los demás es algo ligero, solo un pelín más fuerte que *damn*. Ten en cuenta que como muchas palabrotas, tiene sus usos positivos también, entonces como dices puede ser *maldito*, *jodido*, *me cago en* (usos negativos), pero también podría ser *cojonudo*, *acojonante* (usos positivos), en fin.... según el contexto, podría ser casi cualquier cosa :-)

Comment: @guifa, gracias. Sabía que la F-word es muy fuerte para muchos, pero no sabía de la "GD-word". La verdad es que tiene mucho sentido, viendo como mucha gente dice "Oh my gosh!" o "Jeez!" en lugar de "Oh my God!" o "Jesus!". Siempre pensé que era porque el segundo mandamiento prohibe usar el nombre de Dios en vano. Gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En mi opinión, `maldito` es la mejor traducción.
En los ejemplos que mencionas, se puede sustituir `god damn` por `maldito` y es entendible para todos los hispanohablantes. Por otro lado, términos como `me cago en la leche` y en general `me cago en`, son muy propios de España (según mi entender).

Entonces, los ejemplos que mencionas podrían ser traducidos así:

> God damn running dog... -> Maldito perro...
>
> OWW god damn it-- -> OWW maldita sea--
>
> Goddamn fascist son of bitches... -> Malditos fascistas hijos
>   de puta...
>
> Hiyo Goddamn silver -> Hiyo maldito Silver

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo. "Maldito" es la versión censurada. Si la historieta estuviera inicialmente escrita en español ningún editor sería tan pudoroso para escribirlo así: _¡M-censurado-o!_, porque no es ninguna grosería. En cambio sí se podría con _Hij-censurado-a_ y toda la lista de insultos propios de cada país.

Answer (score 4):

Como para casi todo, no creo que exista "la mejor" traducción para goddamn y que ésta sea invariable.

Es cierto que en casi todos los ejemplos cabía la posibilidad de usar "maldito" o "condenado" pero, si he entendido bien, se encontraban todos en el mismo cómic por lo que el traductor puede haber optado por no repetirse (cosa a la que el castellano, no sé el inglés, es muy sensible estilísticamente), o simplemente ha tratado de acercarse al lector adaptándose a su lenguaje (en registro coloquial oigo poco "maldita sea", en cambio cagarse en la leche está a la orden del día).

Añado una traducción popularísima en España: puto.

*Puto perro...

OWW [me cago en] la puta--

Putos fascistas hijos de puta...*

También, como *goddamn*, puede tener connotaciones positivas: "eres el puto amo".

Es ésta positividad (como apunte curioso) la que tiene tan mala traducción en "Hiyo goddamn Silver". No creo que la elección del traductor sea la más acertada, pero tampoco encuentro ninguna satisfactoria. Se está jugando con "Hiyo Silver" (arre, Silver) pero con un exabrupto intercalado a la manera de "Abso-fucking-lutely". Es un juego en el que el ritmo tiene un papel muy importante, y con "maldito" o "jodido" lo rompemos del todo. Quizás "puto" encajaría mejor por ser bisílabo (hiyo, puto Silver), pero habría que ver el contexto.

También habría que ver si la misma traducción se usa en otros países donde no hay connotación positiva que valga para "puto", en cuyo caso quedaría descartada.