# What is "me cago en la leche de la República"?

Tags: coloquialismos, significado-en-contexto, vulgaridades

In Ernest Hemingway's "For Whom the Bell Tolls", there is a chapter where one of the characters says:

> me cago en la leche de la República.

Although it's an English edition, there are quite a few phrases in Spanish and the above sentence is repeated more than once throughout the book.

Literally, I understand it as "the milk of the Republic", but milk is nutritious and, metaphorically, it might mean any help sent by the Republicans during the Spanish Civil War. The Republicans wouldn't send any help in this case, though.

ps. The edition I read, and where all the swearing was in Spanish, was published when I was around 17 or 18, more decades ago than I care to count. I tried to find it and provide a link but I couldn't.

Comment: Related: [¿De dónde viene la expresión "me cago en la puta"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16732/1674) and [¿Cuál es la mejor traducción para "Goddamn"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/13350/1674)

Comment: The Spaniards often mention milk in their insults and rudeness. Read the comments on this question: [¿Por qué en España "leche" significa "golpe"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16533/6915)

Comment: Are you reading the original? As a Spanish in Spain, the expression "me cago en la leche" sounds well, but not with an "extension" like in here, so I would be interested in seeing the full context, just to see if I am missing something. As [mdewey's answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/40381/1674) explains, it is normally used as a whole.

Comment: leche means sperm. It means literally: I shit on the Republic's sperm. Translation into English: I shit on the Republic.

Comment: @Lambie   Does it?  But it also means milk. (cafe con leche)

Comment: @Centaurus That's the literal meaning. Do you seriously think I don't know that?  I meant to say that leche is ejaculate (c**//can't stand to type that). But I was thinking of porra in Portuguese. The point is that porra and leche are very similar. And said in similar circumstances when people swear.

Comment: @Lambie   I get it.  Thank you.

Comment: @Lambie I doubt most of Spanish speakers would think in "sperm" when hearing "me cago en la leche". Do you have references of that? As you can see in [*leche* definition by RAE](https://dle.rae.es/leche), it has many, many possible meanings, such as "golpe" (hit).

Comment: @fedorqui Please **read** my earlier comment., I said I mis-wrote/mis-spoke. Not sperm, that is for the Portuguese porra. la lecha is slang for **ejaculate**. I associated it incorrectly. Esto seria vulgar, por ejemplo. ! La leche, no voy." En portugués: "Porra, não vou". Puede tener esse sentido y me parece sexual. Because in Portuguese porra is sperm.

Comment: @fedorqui https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/16533/por-qu%c3%a9-en-espa%c3%b1a-leche-significa-golpe//see Rafael. He says semen. OK, same idea.

Comment: @Lambie if a comment is wrong, what is more appropriate is to delete it, since they cannot be edited after 5 minutes. This, or to post a new, fixed one, instead of asking people to follow all the thread of comments and recomments.

Comment: @fedorqui   I've just heard from a native Spaniard that the word "leche" can be feminine as in "la leche", or masculine as in "el leche".  And that its meaning chages accordingly. I've searched the net but found nothing that could bear him out, though.

Comment: @Centaurus the masculine as in "el leche" does not ring a bell to me. What I saw in the Diccionario de americanismos is that the entry [*leche*](https://www.rae.es/damer/leche) just has a masculine entry when it refers to a tree, could it be this one? Note that *leche* is a word that can be heard in many, many different contexts ("mala leche" is bad humour, "qué leche" can be both "what a blow" but also "how lucky", etc)

Answer (score 3):

The thing you need to look up is the meaning of the phrase *cagar en la leche* which according to the [DLE entry for cagar](https://dle.rae.es/cagar?m=form) is

> me cago en diez, o en la leche, o en la mar, etc.
>
> 1. locs. verbs. malsons. coloqs. U. para expresar extrañeza o contrariedad.

So not surprising it is a colloquial expression of disgust. Without more context I cannot say why the speaker is disgusted with the Republic.

I must admit I thought it was an invention of Hemingway but apparently not.

Comment: Yes, where leche means ejaculate in Spanish and where the phrase overall requires rewriting in English to make sense.

Answer (score 3):

[SHADOWS OF A LITERARY DIALECT: FOR WHOM THE BELL TOLLS IN FIVE ROMANCE LANGUAGES (2).](https://www.thefreelibrary.com/SHADOWS+OF+A+LITERARY+DIALECT:+FOR+WHOM+THE+BELL+TOLLS+IN+FIVE...-a068506415)

> Although some scatological Spanish expressions have literal cognates in Catalan--which is hardly surprising, considering the similarity between the two languages and their cultures, as well as the fact that most Catalan speakers are bilingual in Spanish--the Catalan translation of For Whom the Bell Tolls bowdlerizes the juicier insults through use of the **vicarious term "dallonses" (such-and-such, this-and-that) as a euphemism**.(19) Thus "*I obscenity in the milk*" (111, 140) becomes "*Em dallonses en la llet*" (I such-and-such in the milk) (Cat 130, 160). Again demonstrating that insults in another language are less offensive, the rather literal Portuguese translation resorts to italicized Spanish cognates, so that "*Down with the miscalled Republic and I obscenity in the milk of your fathers*" (111) becomes "*Abaixo a infame Republica e me cago (I shit) no leite de vossos pais*" (Pg 97).

> **Muck them to hell together**, Largo, Prieto, Asensio, Miaja, Rojo, all of them. Muck every one of them to death to hell. Muck the whole treachery-ridden country.
> **ROBERT JORDAN**

> Those neither understand nor believe in anything.' "Just then, one of the **drunkards** got to his feet and raised both arms with his fists clenched over his head and shouted, 'Long live Anarchy and Liberty and **I obscenity in the milk of the Republic**!' "The other drunkard who was still lying on his back, took hold of the ankle of the drunkard who was shouting and rolled over so that the shouting drunkard fell with him, and they rolled over together and then sat up and the one who had pulled the other down put his arm around the shouter's neck and then handed the shouter a bottle and kissed the red-and-black handkerchief he wore and they both drank together.

Not an insult, just a drunk taking the piss out of somebody else, not mentioned by an angry specialist in demolitions and explosives.

---

EDIT:

Algunas frases con leche(tal vez ya las dijeron):

- Ser/Fue la leche(ES)
- Vete cagando/jalando leches(ES)
- Los mala leche.(CL)(AR)
- Andas con la leche cortá(CL)  Dicese de la persona que despues de haber efectuado una actividad estresante, no hace mas que dar jugo, es decir, es un pajero.
- ¡A toda leche! (ES)
- Lo infló a leches(ES)
- ¡Por las putas leches!(ES)

A mi entender la frase estaba en inglés, la cual puede ser intepretada como de decir algo obseno, de denigrar pero con sorna, el primer ejemplo(que es lo que creo) que hace alusión los fluidos o a un insulto y no creo que sea el caso el insulto porque el tono es distinto debido a que los personajes que lo dicen son distintos, por lo tanto hay un error en la transliteración. Y, por lo demás la frase "Me cago en la leche de la república" jamás fue mencionada.

Comment: That book was originally in English. So why are you backtranslating here?

Comment: @Lambie This is an English edition and this phrase is also in English:  "I obscenity in the milk of the Republic" and some of the Spanish phrases: Me cago en la leche, me cago en tu padre, me cago en su puta madre, me cago en la leche que me han dado, me cago en tal, but nothing is said of "..república".

Comment: That phrase is meaningless in English. It just doesn't mean anything.  leche here is semen. So that "English edition" is BS.

Comment: @Lambie I didn't say it's not semen.

Comment: I don't understand the point of posting a thing that looks like and read like awful machine translation.

Answer (score 2):

**Español Vulgar /  "Cagarse + Leche + ...  "**

---

*No es fácil una explicación, por la cantidad de aristas que tienen los términos, aunque procurare exponerlo de la forma más adecuada, a pesar de los aspectos más vulgares.*

En esta expresión, *me cago en la leche de la República*, hay que diferenciar a grosso modo dos locuciones distintas, que aunque pueden ir juntas, "cagarse + leche", es mejor hacerlo de forma separada, ya que cada una tiene características diferentes, a no ser que se cague en la leche de una persona. "Me cago en la leche de Robert", cagarse en la leche de la Republica (un ente), ó de otra cosa, aunque se puede decir, es repetitiva, no es una frase que este bien construida y ahora diré porqué, ya que lo que realmente se entiende es simplemente, "Me cago en la República".

---

- **Cagarse en la leche** por si sola, expresa igualmente enfado, molestia, desagrado, fastidio, culparse o culpar a algo ó a alguien y es la versión abreviada ó reducida de la que fue su original;

La locución completa es  "**cagarse en la leche que te han dado**", es decir, aquella leche que tomaste o recibiste al nacer, en el sentido;
"Que llevaría la leche ó quien te dio de mamar de pequeño, que de tan mala calidad era, que mira que mal actúas ahora y el desagrado ó daño que me estas produciendo en este momento".
Resulta en cierto sentido un insulto indirecto ó velado hacia los progenitores, dejando entrever su culpa en la educación y mal carácter ó proceder con que actúa la persona que bebió ó mamo aquella leche inicial.

Aunque el tono utilizado es importante, pues igualmente se puede expresar sin animadversión hacia otra persona, incluso con mofa. En una discusión sin embargo, tendría su mejor equivalencia.
Así podemos decir con más sentido, "Me cago en la leche que te dieron" ó "Me cago en la leche de tu cuñado", cuya sentido para quien no conozca estas expresiones, vendría a decir;

"*Culpo a la mala leche que te dieron ( persona a la que se dirige el improperio), de mamar y me cago en ella (literalmente), (piénsese que la leche esta dentro del cuerpo), como insulto a lo que me estas diciendo, por lo que me estas haciendo pasar, proponiéndome, insinuándome*..., *así que ya sabes el rastro y el mal olor que deja la caca encima de esa malaleche tuya que llevas dentro y lo que cuesta quitarla. ( la persona que se "caga en...", recuerda con estas consideraciones, el alivio, la consolación, tranquilidad y descanso que siente y se produce después de defecar encima de algo que le molesta especialmente)*"

Por ello "Cagarse en la leche de la Republica", suele ser redundante y solo manifiesta molestia, malestar, culpa hacia la Republica, pero no puedes enojarte con la razón que le precedió, en este caso aquello que le diera de mamar, pues en una persona, la leche, en el pensamiento antiguo, quizás tiene que ver con su actual forma de actuar y proceder, pero en un ente, como es la República no cabe tal posibilidad, a no ser que se especifique de manera concreta *a los hijos de la República*, algo que tampoco ocurre ni se sobreentiende en esta frase. Para que la sentencia hubiera tenido alguna especie de sentido más allá de "Me cago en la leche de la República", la frase correspondiente hubiera sido, "*Me cago en la leche de los hijos de la República*". (Ver La Leche más abajo).

---

No obstante, aquí dejo algunas consideraciones y formas más extensas de estos dichos donde se explican algunos aspectos que ayudan a comprenderlos mejor, por si deseas profundizar en ellos. Un saludo.

- **Me cago en**...
  Es una expresión general que indica enfado, irritación, una forma de desahogo y de culpar a algo o a alguien por algún motivo. Como imagen metal esta relacionada con el alivio y descanso que se siente al defecar.

Ejemplos:

De forma frecuente;

- Me cago en el coche, imaginamos que ha sucedido algo con el coche, se ha roto, se ha pinchado, lo han robado... y en parte es una forma de desahogo al culparle de que nosotros estemos en esa situación. También podemos imaginar al conductor subirse al techo del vehículo para literalmente defecar y hallar en ello cierto remedio ó satisfacción a su enojo.
- Me cago en la mar, (Salada, Serena), (Me cachis, alguien tiene la culpa de esto).
- Me cago en Sos, (To'), en todo, estoy enojado con todo en este momento.
- Me cago en la puta, estoy enfadado y enojado y echo la culpa a lo primero que me encuentre o me venga a la mente y que me sirva para desahogarme, hasta con la puta de las cartas (la sota).
- Me cago en "Diez", (se elude nombrar la palabra Dios).

En situaciones más especificas, también puede indicar desprecio por algo ó alguien.

- Me cago en ti, la persona insulta a otra en medio de una discusión, "estoy enojado y tu tienes la culpa de esto". Si pudiera haría mis necesidades sobre ti.
- Me cago en mi vida, uno no esta de acuerdo con su vida ó alguna situación de esta le esta amargando y paga la situación consigo mismo. (Me cago en mis muelas).
- Me cago en la Virgen, se echa mano a una autoridad Celestial para culparle de lo sucedido.
- Me cago en las leyes de la República, la persona no esta conforme con algunas leyes que ha sacado la República y es una manera de insultarla. Si pudiera se "cagaría" encima de esos papeles.

---

La otra expresión;

- **La Leche**

La palabra *leche* está estrechamente vinculada a una antigua creencia referida a la leche materna, así antiguamente se pensaba que a través de la lactancia, el bebé no solo tomaba el líquido, sino también los rasgos de la personalidad de quien le daba de amamantar, de ahí el cuidado en seleccionar a las nodrizas para que no transmitiesen una “mala leche” a la criatura. De esta manera comenzaron a aparecer algunos dichos populares al respecto

- Un malaleche, Persona de mala intención en su carácter. Expresa el aspecto inicial de tomar los rasgos negativos de una personalidad agria ó mal intencionada. Ejem. "Eres un malaleche", "Tienes malaleche". (Duración Permanente)
- Mala Leche, "Estar de mala leche". Enojado, enfadado. Tener un mal momento o un mal día. (Duración Transitoria).
- A mala leche. De forma voluntaria e intencionada, adrede, a cosa hecha.

*Otros dichos con la locución "Leche"*

- De La leche,
  Si algo es de la leche también es lo más de lo más, puede ser positivo (un premio de la leche = un premio maravilloso) o negativo (un golpe de la leche = un golpe terrible).
- A toda leche, se trata de ir, salir, moverse o que impliquen movimiento, se trata de dirigirse a toda velocidad. Estar o sonar 'a toda leche' se refiere a que la música se encuentra a todo volumen.
- Ser la Leche, ser excepcional, fuera de serie pero puede ser excepcionalmente bueno o excepcionalmente malo.
  Ejem. “este tío es la leche” la connotación puede ser positiva o negativa, lo fundamental es hallarlo en el contexto
- ¡La Leche!
  Su interpretación más exacta es impresionante o increíble, y se puede tener "un cabreo de la leche" o "una suerte de la leche"
- ¡Leches!
  lo mismo vale para mostrar asombro, sorpresa, admiración o fastidio.
- Darse una leche
  Viene a significar un golpe o un porrazo.
- Estar con la leche en los labios. (En desuso).
  Se puede utilizar para referirse a quien por su juventud no tiene aún los conocimientos de la edad adulta así como para los principiantes en cualquier profesión.